# Passing a string pointer to a struct in C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, struct

I'm trying to pass various `string`s into members of a `Struct` via `pointer` but I am doing something fundamentally incorrect. What I think is that it doesn't need to be dereferenced. The process below works for other types of data such as `int` or `char`. For example:

```
typedef struct Course {
    string location[15];
    string course[20];
    string title[40];
    string prof[40];
    string focus[10];
    int credit;
    int CRN;
    int section;
} Course;


void c_SetLocation(Course *d, string location){
    d->location = location;
    . . .
}
```

I get an error when I try to compile the following algorithm to initialize a `Course`:

```
    void c_Init(Course *d, string &location, ... ){
        c_SetLocation(d, location[]);
        . . .

    }
```

The error:

`error: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void c_Init(Course*, std::string*, ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually defining, for example, an array of 15 strings in the `location` field. Either use regular strings; e. g.:

```
typedef struct Course {
    string location;
    string course;
    string title;
    string prof;
    string focus;
    int credit;
    int CRN;
    int section;
} Course;
```

or use char arrays:

```
typedef struct Course {
    char location[15];
    char course[20];
    char title[40];
    char prof[40];
    char focus[10];
    int credit;
    int CRN;
    int section;
} Course;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `char a[10]`, you're creating an array of 10 characters. When you declare an `std::string`, you're creating a string that can grow to arbitrary size. When you declare an `std::string[15]`, you're creating an array of 15 strings that can grow to arbitrary size.

Here's what your struct should look like:

```
typedef struct Course {
    std::string location;
    std::string course;
    std::string title;
    std::string prof;
    std::string focus;
    int credit;
    int CRN;
    int section;
} Course;
```

Answer (score 0):

`string location[15]` means that you want to create 15 instances of a `string`, and each of those individual instances can have any length of text.

Instead of `d->location`, you need to assign one of those 15 strings: `d->location[0] = location`, `d->location[1] = location`, etc.