# Passing a string pointer to a struct in C++ (cont)

Tags: c++, string, pointers, struct

This is a continuation of this question, which some nice people already helped me: [Passing a string pointer to a struct in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693638/passing-a-string-pointer-to-a-struct-in-c)

I'm trying to pass various `string`s into members of a `Struct` via `pointer` but I am doing something fundamentally incorrect. What I think is that it doesn't need to be dereferenced. The process below works for other types of data such as `int` or `char`. For example:

```
typedef struct Course{
    string location;
    string course;
    string title;
    string prof;
    string focus;
    int credit;
    int CRN;
    int section;
}Course;


void c_SetLocation(Course *d, string location){
    d->location = location;
    . . .
}
```

I get an error when I try to compile the following algorithm to initialize a `Course`:

```
    void c_Init(Course *d, string *location, ... ){
        c_SetLocation(d, &location);
        . . .

    }
```

The error:

`error: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘std::string* or argument ‘2’ to ‘void c_Init`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

void c_Init(Course *d, string *location, ... ){
        c_SetLocation(d, &location);
        . . .

```
}
```

to

void c_Init(Course *d, string location, ... ){
        c_SetLocation(d, location);
        . . .

```
}
```

There's no reason to pass pointers for location.

Comment: I only did that out of desperation when your suggestion (and the way I thought was the proper way to do it initially) didn't work. I still receive the same error sadly.

Comment: Since you are not modifying location ( I assume) set the paramater as string const &location

Comment: I am modifying it. Well, there is an additional function to do so. But regardless your advice was spot on, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
*location; //this is de-referencing
&location; //this is address of a variable (pointer to a variable)
```

So in order to pass string into c_SetLocation you should de-reference it:

```
 void c_Init(Course *d, string *location, ... ){
    c_SetLocation(d, *location);
    . . .
}
```